# Computing bias for spotlight shadowmap

Tags: opengl, glsl, shadow

after having implemented shadows for spotlight it appears that the bias computaion make the shadow disappear when my spotlight is too far from objects.

I have been trying to solve this problem for two days and I use Renderdoc to debug my renderer so all data are correct inside the shader.

My Case:

**I use a 32 bits depth buffer**
I have two cubes, one behind the other (and bigger to see the shadow of its neighboor), and a light looking toward cubes, they are aligned along the z-axis.

I used the following formula found on a tutorial to calculate the bias:

```
float bias = max(max_bias * (1.0 - dot(normal, lightDir)), min_bias);
```

And I perform the following comparison:

```
return (fragment_depth - shadow_texture_depth - bias > 0.0) ? 0.0 : 1.0;
```

However the more my spotlight is far from objects, the more depth value of the closest cube is close to the depth of the farest cube (difference of 10-3 and it decrease with distance from light).
Everything is working, the perspective made its job.
But the bias calculation doesn't take the distance from fragment to light into account, then if my objects and my light are aligned, `normal` and `lightDir` don't change, therefore the **bias don't change either** : there is no more shadow on my farest cube because **the bias doesn't suit anymore**.

I have searched on many websites and books (all game programming gems), but I didn't find useful formula.

Here I show you two cases:

Here you have two pair of screenshot the colour result from the camera point of view and the shadowmap from the light point of view.

light position (0, 0, 0), everything works
[image]
[image]

light position (0, 0, 1.5), doesn't works
[image]
[image]

Does anybody have a formula or an idea to help me ?
Did I misunderstand something ?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Image with problem will be very useful Also did you try to use more bits for depth buffer (24 or 32)?

Comment: @Unick I edited my post, sure I use a 32 bits depth buffer.

Comment: What value for bias do you use?

Comment: @Unick I don't want to use a fixed bias, I am currentlu computing it like this: `float bias = max(max_bias * (1.0 - dot(normal, lightDir)), min_bias);` with max_bias = 0.05 and min_bias = 0.005. The problem is that this formula doesn't take the light distance into account. (The formula come from [link](http://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-Lighting/Shadows/Shadow-Mapping))

Comment: I think you cannot fix this problem easy. You may try other shadow technics. Also, I can recommend you to look "OpenGL 4 Shading Language Cookbook" and "Real-Time Rendering" books. I think they contain some approach to fix the problem or you may find better technic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You bias the difference which is in post projective space.
The post projective space is non linear as the depth buffer is logarithmic. So you cannot just offset this difference with this bias which is in "world unit".
If you want to make it work , you have to reconstruct your sampling position with this normal offset. 
Or transform your depthes in world space using the inverted projection.

Hope it can help you !

Comment: it's been a while since i last check this post, thank you for your answer, I finally gave up to try to fix this bug when I implemented my little prototype of a rendering engine but your answer will be useful for the future :).